# merge two data.table with a condition

Tags: r, data.table

I have two tables like below
dt1

```
         ID   Date     Code
 1:       1    2015/01    A
 2:       1    2016/01    B
 3:       1    2017/01    A
 4:       1    2015/01    B
 5:       1    2016/01    A
 6:       1    2017/01    B
 1:       2    2015/01    C
 2:       2    2016/01    D
 3:       2    2017/01    C
 4:       2    2015/01    D
 5:       2    2016/01    C
 6:       2    2017/01    D
 7:       3    2015-12-31 F
 8:       3    2016-12-31 G
 9:       3    2015-12-31 F
 10:      3    2016-12-31 G
 11:      3    2015-12-31 F
 12:      3    2016-12-31 G
```

dt2

```
         ID   Date      Code
 1:       1    2015/12    A
 2:       1    2016/12    A
 3:       1    2017/12    B
 4:       2    2015/12    C
 5:       2    2016/12    D
 6:       2    2017/12    D
 7:       3    2016-03-31 F
 8:       3    2016-06-30 G
 9:       3    2016-09-30 G
 10:      3    2016-12-31 H
 11:      3    2017-03-31 I
```

I want to create a table dt3 when the column Code in dt1 is updated with logic below

If ID1=ID2 and Date1 <= Date2 Then Code1 = Code2

```
         ID   Date      Code
 1:       1    2015/01    A
 2:       1    2016/01    A
 3:       1    2017/01    B
 4:       1    2015/01    A
 5:       1    2016/01    A
 6:       1    2017/01    B
 1:       2    2015/01    C
 2:       2    2016/01    D
 3:       2    2017/01    D
 4:       2    2015/01    C
 5:       2    2016/01    D
 6:       2    2017/01    D
 7:       3    2015-12-31 F
 8:       3    2016-12-31 H
 9:       3    2015-12-31 F
 10:      3    2016-12-31 H
 11:      3    2015-12-31 F
 12:      3    2016-12-31 H
```

I tried below but it does not generate what I want

```
dt2[dt1, on=.(ID = ID, date <= date), Code := i.Code]
```

Comment: Are you sure it shouldn't be `C/D/D` for the last 3 rows in the output?

Comment: I *think* you want a rolling join, like `dt1[, Code := dt2[dt1, on=.(ID,DateF), roll=-Inf, .(Code)]]`, but i'm not sure of those last few rows. Where the `DateF` values are full dates created from `dt1[, DateF := as.Date(paste0(Date,"/01"), format="%Y/%m/%d")]; dt2[, DateF := as.Date(paste0(Date,"/01"), format="%Y/%m/%d")]`

Comment: I updated that and also added another example. I basically want to get the code from dt2 with the closet date to the date1. It would be easier to create another table instead of updating so I can compare the results. Thanks for your help @thelatemail

Comment: So you have two different date formats in the `Date` column now - is that intentional?

Comment: Anyway, I'm pretty sure the basic rolling join - `dt2[dt1[, .(ID,Date)], on=.(ID,Date), roll=-Inf]` will do this to give you what you want as a separate table.

Comment: I already fixed the date format issue and have both dates in YYYY/MM/DD format  for both columns in actual dataset. yes, I want Date1 <= Date2 basically taking the code of the closest date2 to Date1.

Answer (score 3):

With proper date formats for both variables, this is a rolling join:

```
library(data.table)
dt2[dt1[, .(ID, Date)], on=.(ID, Date), roll=-Inf]

##    ID       Date Code
## 1:  1 2015-01-31    A
## 2:  1 2016-01-31    A
## 3:  1 2017-01-31    B
## 4:  1 2015-01-31    A
## 5:  1 2016-01-31    A
## 6:  1 2017-01-31    B
## 7:  2 2015-01-31    C
## 8:  2 2016-01-31    D
## 9:  2 2017-01-31    D
##10:  2 2015-01-31    C
##11:  2 2016-01-31    D
##12:  2 2017-01-31    D
##13:  3 2015-12-31    F
##14:  3 2016-12-31    H
##15:  3 2015-12-31    F
##16:  3 2016-12-31    H
##17:  3 2015-12-31    F
##18:  3 2016-12-31    H
```

Using:

```
dt1 <- fread("ID   Date     Code
 1    2015-01-31    A
 1    2016-01-31    B
 1    2017-01-31    A
 1    2015-01-31   B
 1    2016-01-31    A
 1    2017-01-31    B
 2    2015-01-31    C
 2    2016-01-31    D
 2    2017-01-31    C
 2    2015-01-31    D
 2    2016-01-31    C
 2    2017-01-31    D
 3    2015-12-31 F
 3    2016-12-31 G
 3    2015-12-31 F
 3    2016-12-31 G
 3    2015-12-31 F
 3    2016-12-31 G")

dt2 <- fread("ID   Date      Code
 1    2015-12-31    A
 1    2016-12-31    A
 1    2017-12-31    B
 2    2015-12-31    C
 2    2016-12-31    D
 2    2017-12-31    D
 3    2016-03-31 F
 3    2016-06-30 G
 3    2016-09-30 G
 3    2016-12-31 H
 3    2017-03-31 I
")
```